# meteor automatically save geolocation to user document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, geolocation

I would like to automatically track the users on my page.
Their position should be reactively updated in mongoDB.
I would therefore add a new property "location" to the users document.
The mdg:geolocation package already provides a reactive source for the location data provided by the browser:

```
Geolocation.latLng();
```

However, I am struggling to update the user document when the position changes.
How can I trigger the

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: ...});
```

DB update? I tried the following without success:

```
 Meteor.startup = function()
{
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
        var location = Geolocation.latLng();
        console.log(location);
        Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
            $set: {
                   location: {
                        type: 'Point' ,
                        coordinates: [location.lng,  location.lat]
                   }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you say what error you're getting?

Comment: I don't get an error at all. It seems that the tracker autorun is never triggered, since the console.log(location) does not print anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see the error.
It's not:

```
 Meteor.startup = function(){};
```

It's

```
 Meteor.startup(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user:

> By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile
>   (writable by user).

So I think you have to simply change your code in:

```
        Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
            $set: {
                   profile.location: {
                        type: 'Point' ,
                        coordinates: [location.lng,  location.lat]
                   }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed it and it is definitely published since I get the location back from Meteor.users.find().fetch();
The problem is, that the tracker is never triggered and the update therefore does not take place.

Comment: Is geolocation enabled? are you developing on browser or mobile?

Comment: The app runs in the browser (Chrome) and geolocation is on (allow Chrome to share my current location). I also use the Chrome sensor emulation to update the location value.

Comment: I have a similar code for Geolocation and it works. The only difference is that my Tracker.autorun is not inside Meteor.startup